# How to plot a in Plotly from a column name extracted from another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, plotly

I have two sample dataframes given below

```
library(shiny)
df1 <- data.frame(words = c("bat", "vat","cat","mat"), count = c(3420, 2098, 2003, 1501), words_count = c("bat (3420)","vat (2098)", "cat (2003)", "mat (1501)"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(class = c("A","B","C","D"), bat = c(10,0,30,20), vat = c(0,0,10,30), cat = c(20,30,0,10), mat = c(20,20,0,0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Using the code below I want to extract the column name from drop down menu (made from df1) and use the extracted value to plot the bar graph in plotly using extracted value as column in  df2. I am doing this is Rmd.

```
inputPanel(
  selectInput("words", label = "Choose the word",
              choices = df1$words_count, 
              selected = df1$words_count[1], width = '100%')
  )

renderPlot({
# Extract the word from drop down
  col_word <- df1 %>% filter(words_count == input$words) %>% pull(words)

  plot_ly(df2, x = ~category, y = ~col_word, type = 'bar') %>%
    layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), xaxis = list(title = ""))
})
```

I get no output. I have tried a couple of things like get(col_word) however, it does not work.

Comment: There is no column called category in df2 so won't plot. try changing x=~class in your plot_ly call

Comment: @e.matt. Thank you for your reply. I tried changing x=~class. It still does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result `col_word` is a character value (e.g., "bat").

For `plot_ly`, you need a data frame column, or list or vector, not a character string.

You can get around this in `ggplot` using `aes_string`. However, in `plotly` you need an alternative --- you can try:

```
plot_ly(df2, x = ~class, y = ~get(col_word), type = 'bar') %>%
   layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), xaxis = list(title = ""))
```

Or:

```
plot_ly(df2, x = ~class, y = as.formula(paste0('~', col_word)), type = 'bar') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), xaxis = list(title = ""))
```

**Edit**: Make sure to also use `renderPlotly` (note the 'ly' at the end).

Here is a full working example in R Markdown with `shiny`:

````
---
title: "Test509"
author: "Ben"
date: "5/9/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
```


```{r}
df1 <- data.frame(words = c("bat", "vat","cat","mat"), count = c(3420, 2098, 2003, 1501), words_count = c("bat (3420)","vat (2098)", "cat (2003)", "mat (1501)"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(class = c("A","B","C","D"), bat = c(10,0,30,20), vat = c(0,0,10,30), cat = c(20,30,0,10), mat = c(20,20,0,0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

inputPanel(
  selectInput("words", label = "Choose the word",
              choices = df1$words_count, 
              selected = df1$words_count[1], width = '100%')
)

renderPlotly({
  # Extract the word from drop down
  col_word <- df1 %>% 
    filter(words_count == input$words) %>% 
    pull(words)

  plot_ly(df2, x = ~class, y = ~get(col_word), type = 'bar') %>%
    layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), xaxis = list(title = ""))
})
```
````

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions. However, nothing appears. I cannot see the plot.

Comment: Also make sure to use `renderPlotly` (note the 'ly' at the end). See edited answer for working example.